# Can't trigger mouse events on an SVG in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, svg

I'm developing an Angular application centred around an interactive map that has been supplied as an SVG image. Some areas of the map will have hot-points that I can click on to trigger certain events, such as zooming in on a certain portion when I click a location marker.

However, no mouse events work. I can alter attributes of the SVG in TypeScript (change the SVG viewbox for panning and zooming, or highlighting a label in red when an event occurs, for example) but I cannot trigger any click, scroll, hover etc. events within the SVG itself.

Thus far I have tried:

- Adding angular event attributes to the SVG, which obviously aren't valid XML so the browser can't parse it for rendering, and;
- Finding the element by it's ID (which I can) and then attaching an anonymous `onclick` function to it - but it never gets triggered

The SVG is included via an `object` tag.

```
<!--map.component.html-->
<object id="svg-object" #svgObject type="image/svg+xml" data="../../../assets/img/map_large.svg"></object>
```

In my component after the SVG has loaded, I do the following but nothing happens. It doesn't even enter the function.

```
// map.component.ts
this.svgDocument = this.svgObject.nativeElement.contentDocument.documentElement;
let el = this.svgDocument.getElementById("zoomToThis");
// this never gets triggered
el.addEventListener("click", function(event)
    {
        event.currentTarget.style.opacity = "1";
    }
);
```

This, however, works just fine. So it's clear that accessing the document elements isn't the problem.

```
// map.component.ts
this.svgDocument = this.svgObject.nativeElement.contentDocument.documentElement;
let el = this.svgDocument.getElementById("zoomToThis");
el.style.opacity = "1";
```

How can I fix this? I'm toying with the idea of ripping it all out and using vanilla JavaScript in an iFrame, but I've been told that the lead refuses to do that. Given the sheer size of the map, we also refuse to have it inline.

Comment: Can you provide a cut-down demo ([mcve]) that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: I found a solution myself after much trial and error. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56610864/9208795

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've racked my brain over this even outside of office hours and I've found something which works. It feels dirty, but it works.

First, I get the *content window* of the object tag, not the *content document*.

```
// map.component.ts
let cw = this.svgObject.nativeElement.contentWindow;
```

Content Window acts in a similar manner to an iFrame. To have click events work inside the SVG, I can inject a function into the Content Window.

```
// map.component.ts
cw.nameOfMyFunction = (event) => { /* do something */ }
```

Then, inside the SVG itself, I can add click handlers to elements (either by editing the XML directly or in software such as Inkskape).

```
<!--map_large.svg-->
<rect onclick="nameOfMyFunction(event)" />
```

I click the rectangle and the function fires as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HostListener with a function that checks whether the click event is on the SVG element:

```
// map.component.ts
@ViewChild('svgObject')    svgEl:    ElementRef;
@HostListener('click', ['$event.target'])
clickEvent(target: any) {
    if (target === svgEl.nativeElement) {
        svgEl.nativeElement.style.opacity = '1';
    }
}
```

Edit: Another way is to add an onClick event to the element:

```
<!--map.component.html-->
<object id="svg-object" #svgObject (click)=changeOpacity() type="image/svg+xml"data="../../../assets/img/map_large.svg"></object>

// map.component.ts
changeOpacity() {
    this.svgDocument = this.svgObject.nativeElement.contentDocument.documentElement;
    let el = this.svgDocument.getElementById("zoomToThis");
    el.style.opacity = "1";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not what I'm after. As stated, I need to click on hot points within the SVG, not the entire SVG itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the render method to capture events

`this.renderer.listen(document.querySelector('svg'),'click',(evt)=>{console.log(evt)});`

import renderer2 and initiate it in your component constructor

`private renderer: Renderer2`

Comment: This question was answered two years ago. I was also not after clicking on the entire SVG itself, but hotspots within the SVG. This has been resolved by injecting functions into the SVG's content window.